# Professional investment planning for small net-worth individual in bearish market

Tags: investing, shorting-securities, short-term

I would like to find an investment planner that can help me achieve moderately aggressive growth when the stock market is expected to go down. Perhaps he would use shorts and other more short-term techniques. I would only be looking to give the person control of between $50K to $100K. My guess is that I can find local professionals that would be worth the cost. Am I right? How would I find a good planner?

Comment: For what it's worth. The entire market isn't bearish just because the aggregate may be. There are always bullish investments in a bear market to be found.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have a hard time finding a legit investment planner that is willing to do things like take short-term positions in shorts, etc for a small investor. Doing so would put them at risk of getting sued by you for mismanagement and losing their license or affiliation with industry associations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet here.

If you want professional management, because you think they know more about entry and exit points for short positions, have more time to monitor a position, etc... (but they might not) try a mutual fund or exchange traded fund that specializes in shorts.

Note:  a lot of these may not have done so well, your mileage may vary